# Is it true: For prime $p$, all generators of $ (Z/pZ)^* $ are of the form $(2^a \bmod p)$ where $ 1 \leq a < p-1 $ and $a$ is coprime to $ p-1$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory

My lecturer said something about this in class, but I'm not sure I got it correctly.

Is it true that for prime $p$, all the generators of $(\mathbb Z/p\mathbb Z)^*$ are of the form $(2^a \bmod p)$  where  $  1 \leq a < p-1  $    and $a$ is coprime to $ p-1$?

How can I prove this? Thank you.

Comment: That's the case if $2$ is a generator, not in general.

Comment: Can you prove that $2$ is a generator ?

Comment: In $\Bbb Z/5\Bbb Z$, the only powers of $2$ are $1$ and $2$.

Comment: @DanielFischer sorry I edit the post, its 2^a modulo p

Comment: That doesn't change anything (I interpreted $2^a$ modulo $p$ anyway). The question is whether $2$ is a generator of the group. If it isn't, no power of $2$ (modulo $p$) can be one either.

Comment: @DanielFischer So what I wrote is true iff 2 is a generator?

Comment: Yes. And generally, if $g$ is a generator of $(\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z})^{\ast}$, then the set of generators is $\{ g^a : \gcd(a,p-1) = 1\}$.

Answer (score 1):

For example,

$$\;2^3=1\pmod 7\implies \langle2\rangle\neq\left(\Bbb F_7^*\right)\;,\;\;\Bbb F_p:=\Bbb Z/p\Bbb Z$$

and something similar happens with any prime $\;p=\pm1\pmod8\;$ (observe that none of the powers of $\;2\;$ modulo $\;7\;$ is a generator) . You need $\;2\;$ to be a primitive element modulo $\;p\;$, and for that $\;2\;$ need to be a non-quadratic square.

The general case is, I think, considered in Artin's Conjecture.

Comment: In which case  what I wrote is true?

Comment: @CnR As noted in the comments, that is true exactly when $\;2\;$ is a generator of the cyclic multiplicative group $\;\Bbb F_p^*\;$

Answer (score 0):

Note that if $G=(\mathbb{Z}/7\mathbb{Z})^*$, $\langle 2\rangle=\{2,4,1\}$ so $2^1$ is not a generator of $G$. Conversely, $3$ is a generator of $G$ but does not have the form $2^a$ for some $a$ with $gcd(a,7)=1$